# making one text box bigger than others

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap. I am trying to make one text bigger than others. Below is my code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <mat-form-field >
              <input matInput placeholder="Name1"  >
          </mat-form-field>       
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <mat-form-field >
              <input matInput placeholder="Name2" >
          </mat-form-field>       
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name3"  >
        </mat-form-field>

    </div>
```

I want Name3 Text box to be bigger than Name1 and Name2.

Here is how it looks like right now. I want name3 to be longer.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Give a class on name3. then declare `width: 100%;` of that class.

Comment: what class should I give to name3

Comment: It can be any name. Or you can do it using inline style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this. Please let me know if it's work. Thanks

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name1"  >
         </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name2"  >
         </mat-form-field>
      </div
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name3" style="width:100%">
         </mat-form-field>
      </div
   </div
```

Comment: yes, it is working. I understand that my class has col-md-8 instead of col-md-6, but does that make any difference or it worked because you gave the width of 100%.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  tried different percentage and all of them worked. I guess. I guess, I missed it while taking the bootstrap tutorial

Comment: You don't have to work with inline styles, you can also use the bootstrap 4 class "w-100"

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/"